Clickhouse materialized view with or without a table
I started using clickhouse and I noticed there are 2 "types" of ways of using materialized views.
the first one is firstly creating a table with MergeTree engine and "adding" the mv to the table:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view TO my_target_table AS
SELECT toStartOfDay(_timestamp)::Date AS Day, ...
FROM my_source_table

But I also can just use the view without a target_table:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
SELECT toStartOfDay(_timestamp)::Date AS Day, ...
FROM my_source_table

Fox context my source table is currently just a table listening to a RabbitMQ queue. So maybe there are more significant considerations between the 2 methods in more complex cases, but I don't see any differences in my case and I would like to know if I am missing something.

Generally we prefer the former, its more explicit and de-couples the target table from the view. This has management advantages e.g. you can drop the MV without dropping the target table. Additionally, querying the de-coupled target table ensures all optimizations are used - historically (need to test if case still) the latter implicit approach wouldn't use some.
Generally go explicit, create the target table first.

When you don't use TO db.table, then will create .inner.* table
from my perspective TO db.table more flexible
which allow more understable sql command when you need change data structure

DETACH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv
ALTER TABLE db.table ...
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...

